# Sonomotors, Sion: Can this electric car really charge up to 30km only from its solar cells?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, solar-cells

Maybe you have heard about Sonomotors and its futuristic electric car, the Sion.
If not, here is the link to its website: https://sonomotors.com/

[image]

Anyway, the manufacturer claims that this car can recharge up to 30km on one day using its own solar-cells.

I have come to Physics Stackexchange, because I want to know: **Can this be true ?**

(I am looking for well-researched, fact based, answers without any bias for or against this car.)

EDIT: got some good answers... but let's really crack it down... Can we chose Germany for instance, look at the solar radiation per month and compute an expected range per month?

Comment: The words "up to" (i.e. "less than or equal to") are very important here. The only way this claim wouldn't technically be true is if the car could travel _more_ than 30km on one day's charge.

Comment: The other issue is how fast you can drive that 30km. Traveling on a flat test track at a steady 1.25 km/hour for 24 hours would demonstrate the claim, but it isn't very useful in practice.

Comment: @alephzero Good Point!

Comment: Might [skeptics.se] be better suited for this "verify this claim for me" question? It isn't much to do with physics, more of an engineering aspect.

Comment: @KyleKanos Thanks for your comment. I didn't know about that site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but only in the most ideal conditions. Ordinary power usage for an electric car is somewhere in the ballpark of $.2~\rm kWh/km$ (the manufacturer claims $.14~\rm kWh/km$). So if you believe their efficiency claims, the claim is that the car can charge up to $4.2~\rm kWh$ in a day. They also claim an efficiency of $24\%$ for the solar panels, which is high but achievable with current technology.

The brightest places on earth have an average solar irradiance of a little more than $7~\rm kWh/m^2/day$, as you can see on the map [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_irradiance#/media/File:Global_Map_of_Global_Horizontal_Radiation.png). With an efficiency of $24\%$, such a place would require $\frac{4.2~\rm kWh}{.24\times 7~\rm kWh/m^2}\approx 2.5~\rm m^2$ of solar cells on the body. There is no claim on the site for the surface area of the solar cells, but a sedan has a surface area of around $6~\rm m^2$, so it is plausible.

Their claim that you can recharge $30~\rm km$ in *Germany* specifically is ridiculous if you take it as some sort of average. Maybe you can get close a few of the brightest days in the summer, thus *technically* fulfilling the promise of *up to* $30~\rm km$ in day, but the average day is going to be far lower than that, less than $10~\rm km$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your well researched answer! Do you think that you could specify "far lower then that"? How much lower?

Comment: Looking at the map posted, on average in the ballpark of 4 times less, so less than $10~\rm km$.

Comment: So basically there claim to have 30km on one day on a sunny day in Germany, reduces to slightly less than 10km.

Comment: @james No, not quite. I'd expect around $10~\rm km$ on average. So if a sunny day might reach $30~\rm km$, by contrast a cloudy day must be quite a bit less than $10~\rm km$. Solar irradiance can vary by a factor of around 20 depending on weather conditions, so I wouldn't be surprised if you get more like $1~\rm km$ on a cloudy day.

Answer (score 2):

In googling around I find figures of around 24 to 34 kW-hours of energy required for an electric car to go 100 miles. Of course, this all depends on the specific type of car, the road conditions, vehicle speed, etc.., but let's take 24 to 34 kW-hours to go 100 miles as a rough estimate. On Amazon, I found a typical solar panel measuring a bit over 5 feet by 3 feet (=15 sq. ft.) as being rated as giving out 270 Watts (this is almost certainly the wattage under full sunlight conditions). I would expect that 15 square feet of solar paneling is about the upper limit on the amount of solar paneling that one could expect to put on a medium sized car.

So let's do the math. Assuming that the solar panels have a full 12 hours of direct, full sunlight to charge the batteries, that works out to 3.24 kW-hrs of energy that is stored in the batteries. If we use the above estimate of 24 to 34 kW-hours to go 100 miles, then that energy corresponds to about 9.5 to 13.5 miles, which is quite a bit short of the claimed 30 km (=18.6 miles). So I would be a little skeptical of the car maker's claim of about 30 km as being an accurate real-world estimate of the distance that the car can travel (one way, not round trip) after one day of charge unless they did something radical (e.g., drastically reduced the weight of the car, installed some sort of super-high efficiency solar cells, etc.).

Comment: Nice answer... a miss by 5miles does not seem that far fetched to me.